# Email newsletter first empty table cell height issue in Outlook 2013

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, outlook-2013

The first empty table cell in my newsletter is displayed much bigger in Outlook 2013. This is what I have:

```
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#b0bc12" height="10" style="background-color:#b0bc12; height:10px;"></td>
</tr>
```

This works fine on every email client I have tested on but in Outlook 2013, the height seems double the assigned height. I also put the following code in the header but it does not seem to have any effect:

```
<!--[if gte mso 15]>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        body { font-size: 0; line-height: 0; }
        tr { font-size:1px; mso-line-height-alt:0; mso-margin-top-alt:1px; }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

I have similar empty cells further down the newsletter but they are all working fine. Just this first one is having an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook 2013 tends to render images/spacers at double their height if they are below 19px. Adding a style to the `<td>` and styling the font-size and line-height to 1px should fix this.

```
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#b0bc12" height="10" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; background-color:#b0bc12; height:10px;"></td>
</tr>
```